# Google Translate showing in Weebly's editor preview but not live website

Tags: google-translate, weebly

In Weebly's HTML/CSS editor, I am having an issue with the Google Translate dropdown option (Language in English, Spanish) appearing in the editor preview but not on the live website.

I copied and pasted the code directly from Google Translate into the header page of our website using the Edit HTML/CSS function.  This is the code:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                includedLanguages: 'es',
                layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE},
                'google_translate_element');
            }  
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

The dropdown appeared on the live website before, but isn't working now.

I tried viewing the live website with different browsers like Chrome, IE, and Safari, and none of them show the language dropdown.  This happened across my computer and my co-worker’s, on both Mac and PC.

I also checked Adobe Flash in case the plugin version was the issue and I have the most up-to-date version (11).

Any suggestions on where I could look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you found your answer or not I see you posted this 5 months ago. I was having the same issue it seems to have something to do with how weebly loads scripts which causes it to not appear in the published site.

The way I fixed this issue was by doing the following.

1) Add when you edit the weebly template CSS add both scripts to the Header 
meaning between everything between  and  should be between  and

2) Put this div tag in your body where you like to add the drop down.